# Random Obj and Array

Tags: java, arrays, random

Hi I have a snippt of my Homework ...and I am getting a different value from what I should be expecting 
here are my class variables

I have :
seed ....(through scanner should be : 12345 -testing value so I get get the same results as my instructor-)
LenghtOfArray ....(through scanner too)
Final MAX = 8;

I didn't know how to coordonate within my code to get it to work

and I have the for loop :

```
Random Obj = new Random (seed);
int []myArray = new int [LengthOfArray];
for(int i = 0 ; i < myRandomArray.length ; i++) {
    myArray[i] = (int) Obj.nextLong();
    System.out.print(myArray[i] + "  ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Now I am missing `MAX` variable so my output should be :

> `4  4  6  0  4  4  7  0  7  6  5  6`

but I get this :

> `-70013384  64862043  543438317  1940859862  924168001  1943285380  -62817581  -1920529480  541298859  -1439409345  520340403  -1293274375`

so how can I enforce my code to get the out come in the range of my MAX (which is < 8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, first define `MAX` -

```
final int MAX = 8;
```

And use [`Random.nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) to specify the maximum value (exclusive, so `0 - MAX-1`) like

```
myArray[i] = Obj.nextInt(MAX);
```

Finally, you should really rename your `Random` instance (`Obj` is both a bad variable name and poorly capitalized per Java's naming conventions - variables start with a lower case letter). In Java 8+, you might also use `IntStream` and lambdas to write it like

```
Random rand = new Random();
int lengthOfArray = 10;
final int MAX = 8;
int[] myArray = IntStream.generate(() -> rand.nextInt(MAX)) //
        .limit(lengthOfArray).toArray();
System.out.println(IntStream.of(myArray).mapToObj(String::valueOf) //
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```

Comment: hahhahaha thank you so much! I just figured it out after I posted the question ....thank you so much for the quick answer though!! highly appreciated!

Comment: That's great snippet what you have written up there, but I am still a newbie in Java ....But I'll certainly revise it and try to understand it later tonight :)

Answer (score 2):

You probably are looking for [`nextInt(int n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) method from the `Random` class which can be used as:

```
myArray[i] = obj.nextInt(9); //including 8 and 0
```

**PS**: `obj` here is your `Obj`, just that I prefer following *camelCase* convention.

Answer (score 0):

Length of your array should be 12, not 8. Then to get a number between 0 and 8 to store in your array use

> Obj.nextInt(9);